# Использование двойных кавычек (" ") в CMake

Tags: cmake, кавычки

Подскажите, пожалуйста, для чего в `CMake` используются двойные кавычки?

Comment: в смысле для чего? Для строк конечно

Answer (score 0):

В основном для того, чтобы пробелы были не разделителями, а частью строки. Если пробелов нет, то в принципе можно их не использовать. В CMake практически всё хранится как строка.